# Moq, abstract class and virtual properties

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am using `Moq` framework for Mocking.

I have a `SocialWorker` which derives from an `abstract DataWorker` class.

The `SocialWorker` has reference to couple of `Repositories` as a `virtual property`

I am trying to run the following test:

```
private Place _place;
private Mock<IRepository<Resources.Data.Place>> _placeRepositoryMock;
private Mock<SocialWorker> _socialWorkerMock;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _place = new Place {Name = "A"};

    _socialWorkerMock = new Mock<SocialWorker> {DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock};

    IRepository<Resources.Data.Place> placeRepository = _socialWorkerMock.Object.PlaceRepository;

    _placeRepositoryMock = Mock.Get(placeRepository);

    _placeRepositoryMock.Setup(
        repository =>
        repository.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Resources.Data.Place, bool>>>(), null, null))
        .Returns(new[] {new Resources.Data.Place()});
}

[Test]
public void AddShouldAddANewPlace()
{
    var placeManager = new PlaceManager(_socialWorkerMock.Object);

    object placeEntity = placeManager.Add(_place);

    placeEntity.GetType().Should().Equal(typeof (Resources.Data.Place));

    _socialWorkerMock.Verify(
        socialWorker => socialWorker.PlaceRepository.Add(It.IsAny<Resources.Data.Place>()), Times.Once());

    _placeRepositoryMock.Verify(
        placeRepository =>
        placeRepository.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(_place.Name), null, null).First(),
        Times.Once());
}
```

The last verification of this test fails with this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: placeRepository => placeRepository.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(._place.Name), null, null).First<Place>()
```

I am fairly new to Moq and unit testing in general.

Here is the relevant code for your reference:

`IUnitOfWork`

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void CommitChanges();
}
```

`IRepository`

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);

    void Delete(T entity);

    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
                        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                        IList<string> includedProperties = null);

    T FindById(object id);

    void Update(T entity);
}
```

`DataWorker`

```
public abstract class DataWorker : IUnitOfWork
{
    protected ObjectContext ObjectContext;
    private bool _disposed;

    protected DataWorker()
    {
        ObjectContext = new ObjectContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataEntities"].ConnectionString);
    }

    ~DataWorker()
    {
        . . .
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        . . .
    }

    public virtual void CommitChanges()
    {
        ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

`DataRepository`

```
public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityObject
{
    private readonly ObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public DataRepository(ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
            _objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        . . .
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        . . .
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
                               Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                               IList<string> includedProperties = null)
    {
        . . .
    }

    public T FindById(object id)
    {
        . . .
    }


    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

`SocialWorker`

```
public class SocialWorker : DataWorker
{
    private IRepository<ContactRequest> _contactRequestRepository;
    private IRepository<Place> _placeRepository;
    private IRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public virtual IRepository<ContactRequest> ContactRequestRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _contactRequestRepository ??
                   (_contactRequestRepository = new DataRepository<ContactRequest>(ObjectContext));
        }
    }

    public virtual IRepository<Place> PlaceRepository
    {
        get { return _placeRepository ?? (_placeRepository = new DataRepository<Place>(ObjectContext)); }
    }

    public virtual IRepository<User> UserRepository
    {
        get { return _userRepository ?? (_userRepository = new DataRepository<User>(ObjectContext)); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused about what your code is trying to do, the design seems a bit odd.

Firstly, the test you have a problem with is referencing a class `PlaceManager`, which you haven't specified and as that's part of the test, it's difficult to see quite where it's going wrong.

Furthermore, I'm not sure what PlaceManager is for.  Your design has `SocialWorker` with a property providing the `PlaceRepository`, so what is the `PlaceManager` for, and why is it being passed a `SocialWorker`?  Doesn't `SocialWorker` manage its own `PlaceRepository`?

Why aren't you calling `_socialWorker.PlaceRepository.Add(place)`, or rather more neatly `_socialWorker.Add(place)`?

I'm only guessing that `PlaceManger` accesses the `SocialWorker.PlaceRepository` , but I don't see why as the `SocialWorker.PlaceRepository` is a public property, there's nothing to stop anyone using directly and ignoring the `PlaceManager`.  That's if the `PlaceManager` is also some sort of `Repository` for `Place`.

Also, your `IRepository` code has `Add()` as a void, yet the `PlaceManager` returns an `object`.  Why is this not strongly-typed to `Place`?  It seems that is what you're expecting...  And your `PlaceManager.Add()` method returns a `Place`, though the `Repository` `Add()` method is `void`. (is it the same place after it has been persisted to the context?)  Is your `PlaceManager` doing something else with the `Place`?

Perhaps I have the wrong end of the stick?  Could you clarify more what the intent of your code is, over what it does?  Sorry for so many questions, but I'd like to know what your design is supposed to be doing before figuring out why you're trying to verify against a non-virtual...

I think the cause of the specific problem, is that in your verify you're expecting a verify against the `Find`, however, that includes a call to `First()`, which needs to be mocked and can't be, as it's a static extension method, not virtual or abstract.

I'm not sure why you're calling against `First()`, anyway.  The method you're verifying is just:

```
_placeRepositoryMock.Verify(placeRepository =>
   placeRepository.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(_place.Name), null, null),
   Times.Once());
```

That's what will actually be called, as that's the signature of the method in the repository.  You can only check that the interface method is called.

Comment: This is an MVC application. I could have directly called _socialWorker.PlaceRepository.Add(place) from my controller. But I prefer to keep my controllers as thin as possible. Moreover the `PlaceManager` does something more than just normal `CRUD`. For example, finding relevant places from Yahoo!'s `PlaceFinder` service. Plus the `PlaceManager` is there so that in future, the Services/API module can as well access the same bit of code without directly writing code against the `UnitWorker` or `Repository`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the difference between `PlaceManager` and `PlaceRepository` is.  When would one access `PlaceRepository` directly and when via `PlaceManager` (after all, there's nothing to stop anyone ignoring the `PlaceManager`).  Why isn't the `PlaceManager` responsible for the `PlaceRepository`? It really seems like a smell to me, it doesn't appear follow the SRP (SocialWorker is doing too many things and responsibility for `Place`s is split).  `Place`s can be added in at least 2 places, I don't understand the overall design concepts, it seems muddled to me.

Comment: My controllers doesn't even know there exists a worker or repository. All they have access to is a Manager.